# Redux is not passing state to reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to pass the state to the reducer, I'm not sure why I can't retrieve the value. I'm getting the following error

> × Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of
>   undefined

[image]

**action**

```
export const getUser = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
      const url = await Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_GET_USER);
      const response = await url;
      const data = response.data; // renders auth:true or auth:false
      if(response){
          dispatch({type: GET_CURRENT_USER, data})
      }

    }
}
```

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    authError: null,
    isAuthenticated:localStorage.getItem('auth'),
    githubAuth:localStorage.getItem('gitAuth'),
    token: null,
    user: [],
    isAuthenticated2:false,
    redirectPath: null

}

 case GET_CURRENT_USER:
   return({
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated2:action.data.response.auth

   })
```

renders false when `this.props.getUser` is executed

**Front end**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import axios from 'axios';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {compose} from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUser, setCurrentUser} from './actions/';
import setAuthToken from './setAuthToken';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import Axios from './Axios';
import { runInThisContext } from 'vm';


const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: 20
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },

  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: "",
      isAuthenticated: false,
    }

}

componentWillMount(){

  if (localStorage.auth != null) {
    // Set auth token header auth
    setAuthToken(localStorage.auth);

    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth');
    // // Decode token and get user info and exp
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    // console.log(decoded);
    // // Set user and isAuthenticated
    this.props.setCurrentUser(decoded);

  }



    this.props.getUser();

    console.log(this.props.isAuthenticated2);




}



  render() {

    const { classes, isAuthenticated } = this.props;


    return (

      <div className="App">

        <Navbar />



      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  isAuthenticated2: state.user.isAuthenticated2


})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getUser: () => dispatch (getUser()),
  setCurrentUser: () => dispatch( setCurrentUser()),

});


export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withStyles(styles))(App);
```

Edit could it be returning false, because auth:true is an object not an actual boolean ?

[image]

Comment: as per error `action.response` is undefined. Make sure data in ` const data = response.data;` give you a value

Comment: Did you mean to await url? You're already doing an await on the previous line

Comment: it does give a value

Comment: `auth:true` it renders

Comment: You're passing `dispatch({type: GET_CURRENT_USER, data})` so wouldn't it be `action.data.auth`? Did you try console logging the value of action? That would be the first thing to do

Comment: Based on what you're passing to your action creator, it should probably just be action.auth. You're giving it response.data as it's param.

Comment: post here what `console.log(data)` displays

Comment: `auth:true` it renders but its not rendering on the state as true, it renders false.

Comment: `this.props.getUser()` renders false not true, it should be true.

Comment: it renders false because actions is undefined

Comment: ill post updated code on front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per image error occurs here

```
action.response.data.auth
```

and in your code change it to

```
action.data.response.auth
```

you should receive data in reducer action.data.auth

```
case GET_CURRENT_USER:
   return({
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated2: action.data.auth

   })
```

Comment: i tried it, it still renders false, i updated the post. i think the problem is because im fetching from an objectt, would i use object keys or something ?

Comment: still nothing has changed.

Comment: it doesn't seem to update the state no matter what. `console.log(data)` renders a value for sure.

Comment: which lib do you use for async action? thunk? and try log action in reducer  to understand which datatype receiving

Comment: ill accept as answer, i think its a backend issue on express. thanks daviti :)